# error Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-notifications

I'm using Firebase to handle push notifications in my iOS app. All notifications was working fine, but stop working suddenly without touch anything. I'm getting `error Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"` and I have all the APN's certificates created and uploaded in Firebase.

When I receive the JSON from Firebase has not the APN.

Answer (score 4):

The error code is `kCFURLErrorTimedOut`.  Although I can't be certain why it is happening, the error strongly suggests either a network problem (e.g. somebody blocking that port or IP range) or a server outage.

It is also possible that you're hitting Apple's push servers too often and they are throttling you for some reason.

A couple of sites that might help:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6048412?tstart=0
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203609

If the problem doesn't go away on its own, you might want to open a DTS incident.

Comment: I thought error was about certificates, but maybe its about my network, i'll keep searching about this issue.